# ReactJS child component not updating after parent's state chaged

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where after clicking a button, the function updates the state (order) which rerenders the componet but updates only the span's text. Shouldn't the 'i tag' be rerendered as well?

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const SortType = {
  UNSORTERED: { icon: 'fas fa-sort', next: 'ASCENDING' },
  ASCENDING: { icon: 'fas fa-sort-up', next: 'DESCENDING' },
  DESCENDING: { icon: 'fas fa-sort-down', next: 'UNSORTERED' }
}

const Sorter = ({ trigger, sortOrder }) => {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState(SortType.UNSORTERED)

  function onSort() {
    const nSortOrder = SortType[order.next]
    setOrder(nSortOrder)
    trigger(nSortOrder)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortOrder) {
      setOrder(sortOrder)
    }
  }, [sortOrder])

  return (
    <button onClick={onSort}>
      <i className={order.icon}/>
      <span>{order.icon}</span>
    </button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Sorter trigger={console.log} sortOrder={SortType.UNSORTERED} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

**Actual result vs Expected result**

[image: Actual result]
[image: Expected result]

Comment: Where is the rest of the code for the component? Where is the implementation of your onSort function? How do you expect anyone to help you with the code you have provided?

Comment: If the span was updated, it meant `order.icon` was getting new value, it's weird if as you said the `i tag` was still the same, I suspect it. What is class of "i tag" when you inspect it with the devtool?

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn just added a snippet so you can see but it is a svg tag with the following class: svg-inline--fa fa-sort fa-w-10

Comment: @GabrielBrito Was your problem solved? Why didn't you make any response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your **font-awesome's cdn link**. Because as we've all seen, the value of `order.icon` did change, the className of the i tag did change, but then it rendered the weird svg component with an unchanged class of "fa-sort". Just replaced with another cdn link of fontawesome [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome), and it worked properly.

- The code works properly after replacing one line of code from yours:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const SortType = {
  UNSORTERED: { icon: 'fas fa-sort', next: 'ASCENDING' },
  ASCENDING: { icon: 'fas fa-sort-up', next: 'DESCENDING' },
  DESCENDING: { icon: 'fas fa-sort-down', next: 'UNSORTERED' }
}

const Sorter = ({ trigger, sortOrder }) => {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState(SortType.UNSORTERED)

  function onSort() {
    const nSortOrder = SortType[order.next]
    setOrder(nSortOrder)
    trigger(nSortOrder)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortOrder) {
      setOrder(sortOrder)
    }
  }, [sortOrder])

  return (
    <button onClick={onSort}>
      <i className={order.icon}></i>
      <span>{order.icon}</span>
    </button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Sorter trigger={console.log} sortOrder={SortType.UNSORTERED} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<!-- REPLACED HERE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css"> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```